# 401 unauthorized error when registered a MS Teams bot using Azure Bot

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I used "Teams Toolkit [Preview]" in VS2019 to develop a MS Teams bot. If I registered my bot via https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new, I can test that from MS Teams UI without problems. however when I registered the bot from Azure Bot service by using a existing Azure AD application which I created separately, I see "401 unauthorized" error message shown up in my ngrok screen and MS Team bot didn't work. Previously I used "Bot Channel registration" from Azure, it worked fine. As "Azure Bot" replaced "Bot Channel Registration" and "Azure Web Bot", I am trying to figure out why "Azure Bot" didn't work. Can anyone share a latest instruction how to use Azure Bot to create a MS Team Bot?

Answer (score 1):

The steps to create a teams bot is essentially the same, it's just that `Bot Framework Registration` has been replaced by `Azure Bot`. The Azure Bot resource should still have all of the same Configuration and Channel registration options available.

You might find the [Teams conversation bot sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot) helpful. Just remember that on step 4, you'll create an `Azure Bot` resource instead of a `Bot Framework Registration` resource.

You might also check for common pitfalls, such as forgetting to add `/api/messages` in the configuration in Azure, pointing ngrok to the wrong port, or typos of `appId` or other credentials in the bot settings or Teams manifest. These easy to do mistakes can usually cause those errors.